# Python ZeroDivisonError How do I fix this?

Tags: python

In this code below, I obtained `ZeroDivisionError`. How do I fix this? Thank you.

Here's the data I'm using:

[image: Table]

And this is my code:

```
def sim_correlation(data,p1,p2):
    #finding x and y
    list_p1=list(data[p1])
    list_p2=list(data[p2])

    #finding step1 and 2
    sum1=sum(list_p1[index] for index in range(len(list_p1)) if list_p2[index]!=0)
    sum2=sum(list_p2[index] for index in range(len(list_p2)) if list_p1[index]!=0)

    #doing step 3
    pSum=sum([list_p1[index]*list_p2[index] for index in range(len(list_p1)) if list_p1[index]!=0 and list_p2[index]!=0])

    #doing Step 5 and 6
    sum1sqr=sum([pow(list_p1[index],2) for index in range(len(list_p1)) if list_p1[index]!=0 and list_p2[index]!=0])
    sum2sqr=sum([pow(list_p2[index],2) for index in range(len(list_p2)) if list_p1[index]!=0 and list_p2[index]!=0])

    #n-of nummerator
    n=([index for index in range(len(list_p1)) if list_p1[index]!=0 and list_p2[index]!=0])
    n=len(n)

    #nummerator
    num=pSum-(sum1*sum2/n)

    #Denamuerator
    den=math.sqrt(sum1sqr-pow(sum1,2)/n)*math.sqrt(sum2sqr-pow(sum2,2)/n)

    r=num/den #<---------Apparently this is where the error leads but i'm stumped
    return r
```

And last but not least, here's the command I wrote to run this before i obtained the `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

```
sim_correlation(data,"budi","chandra")
```

Comment: Apparently `den` is zero

Answer (score 1):

You may catch the exception, only if it's intended(catching unpredictable exceptions is a very bad practice).

```
try:
    r=num/den
except ZeroDivisionError:
   //special treatment
return r
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this one;

```
if den != 0:
    r= rum/den
else:
    r = 0
```